# Problems establishing connection with DB

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, pymongo

Platform: LINUX.

I am a beginner of MongoDB and pymongo.  After installing pymongo, here is a simple test I tried on ipython:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient();
# Also tried to specify the local host and port number
db = client['myDB']
collections = db['temptables']
collections.insert({'a':'1'})
```

At this point, it chokes.  And in the end, spits out a "Error 111: connection refused" error.  So, I tried invoking MongoDB straight from the terminal and I still got the error below [look at the far end].  So, I searched a bit and tried:

1. removing the lock ( sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock ).  Turns out there was no lock in the first place.
2. sudo mongod --repair
3. I even saw a suggestion to comment out the host and port number from the config file.  Tried that too, didn't work.

None of the above worked.

This is the error I see when I try to invoke mongodb from command line.

---

017-08-17T15:25:30.265-0700 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-08-17T15:25:30.265-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6

### exception: connect failed

Help, please.

Comment: Sounds like mongo isn't running.  What do you get when you execute `sudo ps -ef | grep mongo` ?

Comment: Probably more to the point is that you never actually installed the MongoDB Database in the first place. It's a common enough misconception for this to likely be true. PyMongo is just what we call a "database driver" or software to communicate with the database service. So to work with MongoDB you actually need the service and not just the "driver". See [Install MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/) in the manual for instructions for your specific platform.

Comment: Thanks, I had installed mongodb; confirmed so by running `mongod --version`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mongo server isn't running.

You can confirm this by executing `sudo ps -ef | grep mongod`

If you have mongo installed and in your path,  you can execute:

```
cd && mkdir -p ~/temp_mongo_db && mongod --dbpath=./temp_mongo_db
```

This will launch mongo and place all database files in your home directory under 'temp_mongo_db'.

Finally, in a new terminal window, execute `sudo ps -ef | grep mongod` again.  You'll now see mongod running.

If you want to run mongo in production, you should configure it to be managed by [SystemD](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) or some other init system.

Comment: Yes, this does get the mongo server running!  And I was able to communicate with the server, thanks.  

However, looks like I always have to perform:
`cd && mkdir -p ~/temp_mongo_db && mongod --dbpath=./temp_mongo_db`
in one terminal and communicate with the server in another terminal?  

Is it possible for me to just create a database file, and start creating tables and populating them, like we do with sqlite3?

Comment: @jsk Mongo is a server and therefore doesn't work exactly like sqlite.  What  linux OS are you using? There is a way to set it up to run in the background and start on boot.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: @jsk checkout https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04